# Javascript Disabling Multiple field objects onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onchange

I was using the following script to disable multiple field objects when one field was selected, I have changed the fields so that they no longer have a default value of zero but can have varying values:

JS

```
function disablefield(fieldObj)
{
    var fields = new Array('Seat_1200', 'Seat_1230', 'Seat_100','Seat_130','Seat_500','Seat_530','Seat_600','Seat_630','Seat_700','Seat_730','Seat_800','Seat_830');

    for(var i=0; i<fields.length; i++)
    {
        fieldObj.form[fields[i]].disabled = (fieldObj.value!=0 && fieldObj.name!=fields[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Can anyone suggest a way to detect the current value of the fields seat_xxxx (which are loaded dynamically) integrate it into the above script then disable the all fields when the value one changes. Or alternatively if the field is de-selected i.e. the user changes his mind and selects another option, then the field is set to zero automatically to satisfy the above script re-enabling all the selection options.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the problem from the author I have a new code set.

I would use a Jquery button set to represent all the tables you have. Then selectively disable them based on the result. Below is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/05cpss80/

Buttonsets are really just classed checkboxes but they give you what you need.

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="check1"><label for="check1">Table1</label>
```

As such you can add additional classes to them to stop them from "checking"

```
$('#check2').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

I would recommend you add some css to make it more obvious, but try the fiddle. Click 2, then the button and it will no longer work. (Thus when they make a selection you call disable on whatever tables you need)